# How can I debounce based on an ongoing operation?

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I have an Angular form that will auto-save. The save functionality has several parts and might take a bit. Saving is triggered based on form values changing.

I obviously can use an Observable to debounce the form values changing, but how do I prevent multiple save calls from happening at once?

What I want:

1. User changes some input fields
2. Auto-save is triggered and takes 2s
3. Before that save is completed, user changes more fields
4. Code waits for the current save operation to complete, and then fires off another save call -- and only one, even if there were several fields changed outside of the debounce limit.

I've been digging through RxJS documentation, but it's complicated and I'm not finding anything that fits my use case. I understand I can combine operators, but I am unsure which ones to combine and/or how. There is a debounce() operator that takes another Observable, but this seems to just be an Observable to determine the time to debounce.

Comment: I think if you are doing it correcly, the debounce time would already discard previous requests, only getting the latests ones "It's like delay, but passes only the most recent notification from each burst of emissions."

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look on `exhaustMap` https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/exhaustMap.